# Size of String array

Tags: esp8266, string, array

I am trying to find out the size of an array like this:

```
    String days[3] = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed" };
Serial.printf("Size of array: %2d\n", sizeof(days));
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(days); i++) {
    Serial.print(days[i]);
}
```

The result of the code above is 36 which is incorrect.

Do I have any other options considering that I don't know the size of the array to begin with?

Comment: sizeof() is the number of bytes and not the number of elements. sizeof(array) / sizeof(element) gives the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the result is correct, you're just interpreting it incorrectly. If you want the number of elements in a statically-allocated array use:

```
sizeof(somearray) / sizeof(somearray[0])
```

Comment: Sorry if I post in wrong topic
follow answer of Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, in case of size of each String in array is different? like String days[] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday" }; Thanks